# Why doesn't the locale change on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, locale

I'm trying to use `strftime` on a mac to output the time in a locale-dependent way.

I'm setting the locale and getting the time :

```
// sets the program's locale to the native locale
// without this line the locale is 'C'

log.debug(setlocale(LC_ALL,"")); 
struct tm* date = localtime(&time);
strftime(result.buf, size, "%X %x", date);
log.debug(result.buf);
```

which outputs

```
en_GB.UTF-8
13:58:01 25/10/2011
```

which is correct. However, I then go to the Language & Text System Preferences panel, and change the region to United States. If I run my program again, I get the same locale, and the time is formatted the same way (I'd expect the locale to be `en_US` and the date to be formatted `10/25/2011`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the terminal or whatever you're starting your program from for changes to take effect.

Comment: From the docs, calling `setlocale()` with the parameter `""` should return the system locale. If that's not the case, how should I be writing this function?

Comment: `Only three locales are defined by default: the empty string "" (which denotes the native environment)`

Comment: I see now what you're getting at.

Comment: oops. hit enter to early. I think after changing the system locale you should *at least* restart the terminal or whatever you run your program from. Have you tried it?

Comment: I've added a comment to the question to make things a little clearer

Comment: Restarting the terminal fixed it, add this to your answer! (Or add another).

Comment: Here we go, originally I totally misunderstood your question. Twice. Sorry about it, I changed the answer.